# angular Cannot emit array

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-components, angular-event-emitter

In `DateRangeComponent` I'm trying to emit array on button click to another (`ViewerComponent`) component using `EventEmitter` and `Output` decorator.

There is a `getData()` method in `DateRangeComponent` where `EventEmitter` emit an array from service.

```
@Output() dataEmitter = new EventEmitter<any[]>();

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  getData() {
    let fromDate = this.dateName[0];
    let toDate = this.dateName[1];

    this.dataService.findNameByDate(fromDate, toDate)
      .map(names => {
          this.names = names;
          this.dataEmitter.emit(this.names);
          //console.log(JSON.stringify(this.names));
        }
      )
  }
```

Component should receive emitted array using `Input` decorator:

```
@Input() names: any;
```

and there is a property binding in HTML:

```
<app-table *ngIf="selectedDate" [names]="names"></app-table>
```

but there is a problem with receiving. What's wrong?

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/3-components-communication?file=app%2Fviewer%2Fviewer%2Fviewer.component.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your emitter is working fine. Problem is with the receiver component.

You are mixing `@Input()` with `@Output()`. You do not need to have `Input()` variable to receive the event emitted, you need to register the `Output` event instead.

Register the `Output` event in your receiving component as `(dataEmitter)="names = $event"`

```
<app-date-range (dataEmitter)="names = $event"></app-date-range>
```

And instead of decalaring name as `@Input() names: any;`

simply declare it as

`names : Array<{}>;`

Forked [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/3-components-communication-lczchy)

Comment: `@Output` emit works only the first time. Is that commonly behaviour for `EventEmitter`?

Comment: Whenever an event is emitted, the subscriber  is triggered. You can emit it as many times as you want. But @Output event is limited to child-parent. If you want to pass it for sibling element then it has to be via the parent component.

Answer (score 1):

Several things.

Your appComponent must be like:

```
//app.html

    <!--we use (dataEmiter) to get the changes, and [names] to send the properties -->
    <app-date-range (dataEmitter)="emit($event)"></app-date-range>
    <app-viewer [names]="names"></app-viewer>

//And the component like
export class AppComponent  {
 names:any[]=[];  //<--declare a variable
 emit(data:any[])
 {
   this.names=data;
 }
}
```

In your vievewer component, not put *ngIf if app-table tag, I choose put in the div and using names.length

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" *ngIf="names.length">
    <app-table [names]="names"></app-table>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want simulate a get, change the service function findByDate like

```
findNameByDate(fromDate: String, toDate: String) {
    return Observable.of(this.data);
  }
```

Of course, the date-range function must be

```
getData() {
    let fromDate = this.dateName[0];
    let toDate = this.dateName[1];

    this.dataService.findNameByDate(fromDate, toDate)
      .subscribe(names => {  //<---subscribe
          this.names = names;
          this.dataEmitter.emit(this.names);
          console.log(this.names);
        }
      )
  }
```

Comment: In real use case there is an Observable: `findNameByDate(fromDate: String, toDate: String): Observable<any[]> {
        return this.http.get(`${this.api}/${fromDate}/${toDate}`)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .catch(
                (error: Response) => {
                    return Observable.throw('Cannot get data from');
                }
            );
    }`  , but I didn't succeed to reproduce it on stackblitz. It throws `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` error

Comment: @corry I told you that if you want "simulate" a "get", you can use Observable.of(...). NOTE: if you use httpClient (if not, you should be) not need map to json. If you received a "Unexpected token <" is because you are not receiving a json, else an error page or similar, you can check it if you see the response in the navigator developer tools